# How can I get rid of the parentheses in the dataframe column?(Python)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

[image]

I want to remove the parentheses in the Movie_Name column.

Here is a few example

```
df_Movie["Movie Name"].str.findall(r'\([^()]*\)').sum()

['(500)',
 '(Eksiteu)',
 '(Mumbai Diaries)',
 '(Geukhanjikeob)',
 '(Erkekler Ne İster?)',
 '(The Witch)',
 '(Ji Hun)']
```

And then ı tried this solution.

```
import re
df_Movie["Movie Name"] = df_Movie["Movie Name"].str.replace(r'\([^()]*\)', ' ', regex = True)
```

**Here is the output of the solution for one example**.

```
df_Movie.iloc[394, :]
Movie Name      Days of Summer
Year                      2009
IMDB                       7.7
Name: 394, dtype: object
```

**In this case, the values ​​between the parentheses are completely lost. I don't want that.**

**I want output like this : (500) Days of Summer --> 500 Days of Summer**

**How can ı solve this ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all parentheses from a dataframe column using

```py
df_Movie["Movie Name"] = df_Movie["Movie Name"].str.replace(r'[()]+', '', regex=True)
```

The `[()]+` regex pattern matches one or more `(` or `)` chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KuIzl8/1).